# Override the maximum size of WizardSmallImage

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I'm trying to set a custom image for the WizardSmallImage of a installer I'm making, but, I have run onto a problem: the image I'm trying to use exceeds the max size for WizardSmallImage (55x58). Since I'm doing this for a friend, I can't cut/shrink his image.

So, is there any way to override this max size?
I have tried to change the properties of WizardForm.WizardSmallBitmapImage  manually by writing this code in the [Code] section:

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  WizardForm.WizardSmallBitmapImage.Stretch := false;
  WizardForm.WizardSmallBitmapImage.Width := 150
end;
```

But it didn't work...

If anyone could answer me, I would be really grateful!!

Comment: You have to move the image to Left. So you have to change `WizardForm.WizardSmallBitmapImage.Left` parameter by diminishing it's value by the difference between standard WizardSmallBitmapImage dimention and yours new and shrinking the label space. Example: `WizardForm.WizardSmallBitmapImage.Width := ScaleX(150);
   WizardForm.WizardSmallBitmapImage.Left := WizardForm.WizardSmallBitmapImage.Left - ScaleX(93);    WizardForm.PageNameLabel.Width := WizardForm.PageNameLabel.Width - ScaleX(95);
   WizardForm.PageDescriptionLabel.Width := WizardForm.PageDescriptionLabel.Width - ScaleX(95);`
 
.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you increase `Width` of `WizardSmallBitmapImage` it overlaps right edge of the window. You have to move it to the left too.

If you need to make it too wide (150), you also need to make the labels (`PageDescriptionLabel` and `PageNameLabel`) to the left more narrow.

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard;
var Diff: Integer;
begin
    ....
    Diff := ScaleX(150) - WizardForm.WizardSmallBitmapImage.Width;
    WizardForm.WizardSmallBitmapImage.Width := 
        WizardForm.WizardSmallBitmapImage.Width + Diff
    WizardForm.WizardSmallBitmapImage.Left :=
        WizardForm.WizardSmallBitmapImage.Left - Diff;
    WizardForm.PageDescriptionLabel.Width := 
        WizardForm.PageDescriptionLabel.Width - Diff;
    WizardForm.PageNameLabel.Width := 
        WizardForm.PageNameLabel.Width - Diff;
    ...
end;
```