# Inno Setup change Small Wizard Image position and size

Tags: inno-setup

I have already read the question [How to change the size of small wizard image and have custom fields in inno setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193811/how-to-change-the-size-of-small-wizard-image-and-have-custom-fields-in-inno-setu), but am still unclear how to actually change the size and position of the Small Wizard Image using `WizardForm.WizardSmallBitmapImage`. Could someone please explain this in a little more detail? I am trying to remove the small white column to the right-hand side of the image and/or increase the width of the image.

```
WizardForm.WizardSmallBitmapImage.Left := WizardForm.InfoBeforePage.Right - 55;
```

doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You will find your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28434906/override-the-maximum-size-of-wizardsmallimage/28435413#28435413)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the white space to the right-hand side of the default sized Small Wizard Image, you can use the following code:

```
WizardForm.WizardSmallBitmapImage.Left := WizardForm.InfoBeforePage.Left + WizardForm.ClientWidth - 55;
```